# Getting values of dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get the values of some dynamically created input forms, here is what I'm trying to do:
Here I'm creating the input forms:

```
const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

and here I'm trying to get their values:

```
// Get a static NodeList of inputs with ID starting with "player"
let players = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=player]');
// Iterate over list, adding a value
const arr = [];
for (let i =0; i < players.length; i++) {
   arr.push(players[i].value);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);` - Why a numbered id and not a common class (e.g. `player`)

Comment: What's the actual problem here? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: `const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');` - The Storage API only knows strings, so you compare a number with a string in `i < x` - which only works because JavaScript will cast the content of `x` for you into a number. You shouldn't rely on such things, unless you really know what's happening.

Comment: You are not setting the value, that's why you are getting an array of `empty string`

Comment: set `value` like `// newInput.setAttribute("value","random-value"`);`

Comment: What format of data is stored in localStorage? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @DeC I don't want to hardcode a value, it should be given by the user.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it's an integer, the number of players.

Comment: so you need to listen `onChange` event and set or use the value according to it

Comment: @Andreas I'm using player${I} because for every player I want to do certain things, I need player0, player1, player2 ...

Comment: @DeC how can I do that ?

Comment: ok - so cast it as an integer - ie `i < Number(x)` etc

Comment: @Andreas if I did only "value", how can I get the input fields values.

Comment: @MoeG You need to listen to `change`event and do what you want with the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to `change` event listener of all `input` element. And you can do whatever with the data in `e.target.value`

```js
const x = 5;
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

const players = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; ++i) {
    values.push(players[i].value);
  }
  console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<div id="player-list"></div>
<button> Print names </button>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, when I do that, I get whatever I type in the input field console logged, I only want the value, how can I do that ?

Comment: I'm loggin the value using `console.log`. You can access the value as `e.target.value`.

Comment: Please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: for example I want to enter the names of John and Mark, here is what I get: ["m", "ma", "mar", "mark", "j", "jo", "joh", "john", "John"]

Comment: You can do this using the `change` event or add a button. When you click the button then you can fetch all values.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want your names in array?

Comment: "What exactly do you want? Do you want your names in array?", that's exactly what I want

Comment: Can we use an button ?

Comment: how can we use a button ? do you mean a button to submit the names, if so I'm already doing it.

Comment: @MoeG answer updated. Is this what you want